# Time Series "status" calculation

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**Sample data:**

```
rep_signup_date rep_id client_registration_date client_id 
1/2/2018        1      1/5/2018                 1          
1/2/2018        1      1/9/2018                 2
1/2/2018        1      2/15/2018                3
1/4/2018        2      2/3/2018                 4
1/4/2018        2      3/9/2018                 5
2/1/2018        3      2/2/2018                 6
```

The way we categorize rep "status" is based on # of clients:
1 client - status 1, 2 clients - status 2, 3+ clients - status 3, so at current date we know the following:

```
select rep_signup_date, rep_id,  
case when count(client_id) over (partition by rep_id) >=3 then '3'
     when count(client_id)  over (partition by rep_id) =2 then '2'
     when count(client_id)  over (partition by rep_id) =1 then '1'
     end status
from reps r
left join clients c on c.rep_id=r.id

rep_signup_date rep_id  status
1/2/2018        1       3     
1/4/2018        2       2
2/1/2018        3       1
```

However, these statuses are as of current date; I tried adding `date_trunc('month', client_registration_date)::date` for month but it still gives data as current snapshot based on max date, not as a static point in time.

What I would like to be able to do is get the status at the end of each month- for example rep id 1 at end of January was status 2.

**Expected output:**

```
rep_signup_date rep_id month    status
1/2/2018        1      1/1/2018 2
1/2/2018        1      2/1/2018 3     
1/4/2018        2      2/1/2018 1
1/4/2018        2      3/1/2018 2
2/1/2018        3      2/1/2018 1
```

How can I get there? Thank you.

Comment: Sample data *and* desired results would convey what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff both provided,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `order by`:

```
select rep_signup_date, rep_id,  
       (case when count(client_id) over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) >= 3 then '3'
             when count(client_id) over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) = 2 then '2'
             when count(client_id) over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) = 1 then '1'
        end) as status
from reps r left join
     clients c
     on c.rep_id = r.id;
```

You appear to have one row per client/rep, so this is much simpler using `row_number()` rather than a cumulative count:

```
select rep_signup_date, rep_id,  
       (case when row_number() over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date ) >= 3 then '3'
             when row_number() over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date rows) = 2 then '2'
             when row_number() over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date = 1 then '1'
        end) as status
from reps r left join
     clients c
     on c.rep_id = r.id;
```

And this can be further simplified to:

```
select rep_signup_date, rep_id,  
       (case row_number() over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date ) >= 3
             when 1 then '1'
             when 2 then '2'
             else '3'
        end) as status
from reps r left join
     clients c
     on c.rep_id = r.id;
```

Or even:

```
select rep_signup_date, rep_id,  
       greatest(row_number() over (partition by rep_id order by client_registration_date ), 3) as status
from reps r left join
     clients c
     on c.rep_id = r.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I added date_trunc('month', client_registration_date)::date and the output seems daily: sort of rep id =1, month = Jan, status = 1, then rep id = 1, month = Jan, status =2; but I only need the status=2 record (As it would be if was by month). Thank you!